# Getting Zurb Foundation `.row .row` error, but am unsure why

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am aware the `.row .row` problem occurs when you two .row elements not seperated by a column element.

However, my markup is as follows:

```
<div class="row content">
  <div class="large-5 none show-for-medium columns">
    <div id="panel">
      <ul class="row">
         <li class="columns">
           <div class="row"><!--THIS IS THE ELEMENT AFFECTED-->
             <div class="small-9 columns"></div>
             <div class="small-3 columns"></div>
           </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-7 columns">
  </div>
</div>
```

Apart from `#panel`, all the mark up seems to be to Foundation's specs.

I tried removing the `#panel` div altogether, but got the same result.

Would anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Seems to work if you set `list-style: none;` to the `ul` or `li` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWjPVB  also you are missing a closing quote on `<div class="small-3 columns></div>`

Comment: Good catch on the quotes, but your example still has the same problem

Comment: Where are you getting an error? Do you have to compile something? I'm not familiar with foundation outside of the basic grid docs I've read from answering questions on here.

Comment: @MichaelCoker if you inspect the .row element (that holds .small-9 and .small-3) you will see that there is a class applied to it: `.row .row`. This usually indicates that there are 2 .rows not seperated by columns,

Comment: That's not what `.row .row` means - that means there is a nested `.row` in an existing `.row`. You will see that any time there is a `.row` in another `.row`. It's like seeing `div div` - you could put a `section`, `article`, and a `form` in between the 2 divs, but if you have a `div div` style in your CSS, you'll see that in the inspector.

Comment: 2 `.row`'s not separated by columns would be `.row > .row`

Comment: that's also not an error. It's foundation accounting for the negative margin on any nested row.